# Laravel - Validation with 'exists' including also "ALL"

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-validation

I have a table which holds post_types. When a user wants to search for post_types I must validate whatever they select from the form. I plan to allow them to search for specific one single type or ALL types at once (no plan to allow them multiple selection yet). So my select has something like this

```
['all' => 'all',
1 => 'User Post',
2 => 'Editor Post',
3 => .... etc]
```

My 'all' value is not exist in `post_types` table so a validation rule like `exists:post_types,id` would not work. How else can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to create your custom validation rule?

```
Validator::extend('availablePostTypes', function($attribute, $value,  $parameters, $validator) {
        $isAvailable = false;

        if ($value === 'all'){
            $isAvailable = true;
        }

        // query for existence
        else {
            $count = Post::where('type', $value)->count();
            $isAvailable = (0 < $count);
        }

        return $isAvailable;
    });
```

Finally, just call the rule:

```
$rules = [
    'post_types'=> ['availablePostTypes'],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which Laravel version it is, so I'll suppose it's the latest stable one (5.1) at the time being.

Given we're in a controller method, you could do something along the lines of

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{

  if ($type = $request->post_type != 'all') 
  {
    $data = Post::whereType($type)->get();
  }
  else
  {
    $data = Post::all();
  }

  // the rest of your code

}
```

Please do note this is just a proof of concept, and you might delegate the same task to a different class if that's what you want.

Hope this helps!